# Auto scroll DataGridView while typing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have this problem where the last column in DataGidView is too long and you need to use scroll bar to go to show the rest of that column.
But when I type a text, it will not auto scroll while typing.

What I want is that I want to auto scroll the scroll bar when typing so that the user will not have to use the scroll bar while typing.

Here is the image:

[image: The datagridview]
As you can see the last column is memoranda.
When I type a text in memoranda it will not auto scroll. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See whether the cells scroll behavior modified in this manner can be of use in your context.

The entered Cell is measured with [DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcelldisplayrectangle)   and, if it's `Right` position falls beyond the `DataGridView` bounds, the `Cell` before the current is set as the [FirstDisplayedCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedcell).
This should ensure that a Cell is always scrolled into view when entered.
When in edit mode, the Cell's bounds will expand automatically.

Also, check the `cutOverflow` parameter of the `GetCellDisplayRectangle()` method for a slightly different behavior when considering a `Cell` bounds extent.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    Dim cellArea = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, False)
    If cellArea.Right > DataGridView1.Width AndAlso e.ColumnIndex > 0 Then
        DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex - 1, e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```