# DataGridView is not scrolling horizontally

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scroll

I'm creating Winform DataGridView programmatically. I need to create several different lists so I'm adding each column dynamically.
The problem that I'm facing is when the sum of all the columns' width is greater than the DataGridView width.
The horizontal scrollbar shows correctly, works correctly when I move it, but, when I press TAB to go to a cell that is outside of the DGV visible range, is not scrolling automatically.
Below is how I´m setting the DGV, being "this" the DataGridView itself.

```
  public DataGridViewCellStyle GridStyle()
  {
     // Set the column header style.
     DataGridViewCellStyle columnHeaderStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
     columnHeaderStyle.ForeColor = DataFormatting.RegularForeColor;
     columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = DataFormatting.RegularBackColor;
     columnHeaderStyle.Font = DataFormatting.FontBold;
     return columnHeaderStyle;
  }

  public DataGridViewCellStyle GridStyleAlternate()
  {
     DataGridViewCellStyle oAlternas = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
     oAlternas.BackColor = DataFormatting.AlternateBackColor;
     oAlternas.Font = DataFormatting.Font;
     return oAlternas;
  }

  public void GridFormat()
  {
     //Estilo de los cabezales de las columnas
     this.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = GridStyle();
     this.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = GridStyleAlternate();

     // Formato del grid
     this.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
     this.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
     this.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
     this.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
     this.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
     //this.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.ActiveBorder;
     this.Font = DataFormatting.Font;
     this.MultiSelect = false;
     this.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
     this.ShowCellErrors = false;
     this.ShowEditingIcon = false;
     this.ShowRowErrors = false;

     //Set the edit mode to "on enter" so that when a cell gains focus it automatically enters editing mode
     this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
     this.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells | DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedHeaders;
     this.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
     this.RowHeadersVisible = true;
     this.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect | DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hm, the default DGV scroll upon tabbing here. Not sure if any of your settings would prevent that..

Comment: I know. This is the first time that I need to create a DGV programmatically, and I don't know where to go from here. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This one is written in vb.net, but easy to translate: [Auto scroll DataGridView while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604395/auto-scroll-datagridview-while-typing-in-vb-net?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: That's good! Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it.

```
  protected override void OnCellEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnCellEnter(e);
     if (!this.CurrentCell.Displayed)
     {
        this.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
     }
  }
```

Even though it is an odd behavior. When, on columns creation, the sum of the widths of the columns is narrowest than the width of the DGV control, and then, I increase (manually with the mouse) the width  of the columns going beyond the DGV width, it works fine, as expected.
But, when the sum of the widths of the columns is widest, is when this piece of code is needed.
Hope this helps someone, even if is not an elegant solution.